# Matrices in Scala

Tags: scala, matrix

I am working on a restricted Boltzmann machine in Scala, for my class...yes I'd rather use python. Anyway, I have errors that I honestly have no idea how to fix. The error that I am having is that the error of each epoch in the machine as it learns does not decrease. Since Scala does not have its own matrix class, I created my own and I believe it all works... Since the epoch error does not decrease and after spending hours on this assignment, I have resorted to posting the code here. If you notice any bugs in this section of code, please let me know. Thanks!

```
    import scala.util.Random

    class Matrix2D (private var sizeX: Int, private var sizeY: Int) {
      private var matrix = Array.ofDim[Double](sizeX, sizeY)
      implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean) = if (b) 1 else 0
      var randomGenerator = new MersenneTwister(1234)

      //insert is for inserting a new row or column, is inserted to beginning of either rows or columns
      def insert(axis: Int): Unit ={ //works
        if (axis == 0){
          sizeX += 1
          val t = Array.ofDim[Double](sizeX, sizeY)
          matrix = copy((1,0), matrix, t)
        } else {
          sizeY += 1
          val t = Array.ofDim[Double](sizeX, sizeY)
          matrix = copy((0,1), matrix, t)
        }
      }

      def insert(axis: Int, value: Double): Unit ={ //works
        if (axis == 0){
          sizeX += 1
          val t = Array.fill(sizeX, sizeY)(value)
          matrix = copy((1,0), matrix, t)
        } else {
          sizeY += 1
          val t = Array.fill(sizeX, sizeY)(value)
          matrix = copy((0,1), matrix, t)
        }
      }

      //insert both row and column
      def insert(offset: (Int, Int)): Unit ={ //works
        sizeX = sizeX + offset._1
        sizeY = sizeY + offset._2
        val t = Array.ofDim[Double](sizeX, sizeY)
        matrix = copy(offset, matrix, t)
      }

      def insert(offset: (Int, Int), value: Double): Unit ={ //works
        sizeX = sizeX + offset._1
        sizeY = sizeY + offset._2
        val t = Array.fill(sizeX, sizeY)(value)
        matrix = copy(offset, matrix, t)
      }

      //this enables the insert to work properly
      //works
      private def copy(offset: (Int, Int), source: Array[Array[Double]], destination: Array[Array[Double]]): Array[Array[Double]] ={
        var dx = Math.abs(0 - offset._1)
        var dy = Math.abs(0 - offset._2)
        for(i <- offset._1 to destination.length - 1){
          for (j <- offset._2 to destination(1).length - 1){
            destination(i)(j) = source(i - dx)(j - dy)
          }
        }
        destination
      }

      private def set(a: Array[Array[Double]]) = matrix = a //works

      //populate matrix with random stuff
      def populate(seed: Int): Unit ={//works
        var r = new Random(seed)
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            matrix(i)(j) = Random.nextDouble()
          }
        }
      }

      def populate(seed: Int, generator: (Double, Double) => Double): Unit ={ //works
        //double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
        var min = -1*generator(sizeX, sizeY)
        var max = generator(sizeX, sizeY)
        var r = new Random(seed)
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            matrix(i)(j) = min + (max - min) * randomGenerator.nextDouble()//Random.nextDouble()
          }
        }
      }

      def populate: Unit ={ //works
        var r = Random
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            matrix(i)(j) = Random.nextDouble()
          }
        }
      }

      //I have no idea if this works correctly
      def dot(other: Matrix2D): Matrix2D ={
        var t = matrix
        t.zip(other.matrix) map { case(te, oe) => te.zip(oe).map { case (a,b) => a*b}}
        //t.zip(other.matrix) map (_.zipped map (_ * _))
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      //make the matrix < 0
      def unary_-(): Matrix2D ={
        var t = matrix
        for(i <- 0 until t.length - 1; j <- 0 until t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = -t(i)(j)
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      //if one matrix is less than the other, make a 2darray of numerical boolean statements
      def >(other: Matrix2D): Matrix2D = { //idk if this works correctly
        var om = other.matrix
        var newMatrix = Array.ofDim[Double](matrix.length, matrix(0).length)
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for (j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            try {
              if (matrix(i)(j) > om(i)(j)) {
                newMatrix(i)(j) = 1
              } else {
                newMatrix(i)(j) = 0
              }
            } catch {
              case e: Exception =>{}
            }
          }
        }
        Matrix2D(newMatrix)
        /*var t = matrix
        t.zip(other.matrix) map { case(te, oe) => te.zip(oe).map { case (a,b) => (a > b):Int}}
        Matrix2D(t)*/
      }

      //negate a matrix from another
      def -(other: Matrix2D): Matrix2D = { //i think this works correctly
        var l = Array.ofDim[Double](matrix.length, matrix(0).length)
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1) {
            try {
              l(i)(j) = matrix(i)(j) - other.matrix(i)(j)
            } catch { case e: Exception => {}}
          }
        }
        Matrix2D(l)
        /*var t = matrix
        t.zip(other.matrix) map { case(te, oe) => te.zip(oe).map { case (a,b) => a - b}}
        Matrix2D(t)*/
      }

      def /(value: Double): Matrix2D ={ //idk if this works correctly
        var t = matrix
        for(i <- 0 to t.length - 1; j <- 0 to t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = t(i)(j) / value
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def *(value: Double): Matrix2D ={ //idk if this works correctly
        var t = matrix
        for(i <- 0 to t.length - 1; j <- 0 to t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = t(i)(j) * value
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def ^(value: Int): Matrix2D = { //this works I think
        var t = matrix
        val m = matrix
        for(i <- 0 to value-2) {
          t = mult(t, m)
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def mult(a: Array[Array[Double]], b: Array[Array[Double]])(implicit n: Numeric[Double]) = { //called by previous def (^)
        for (row <- a)
          yield for(col <- b.transpose)
            yield row zip col map Function.tupled(_*_) reduceLeft (_+_)
      }

      def T: Matrix2D ={ //this works
        var t = matrix.transpose
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def exp(matrix: Matrix2D): Matrix2D ={ //this works
        var t = matrix.matrix
        for(i <- 0 to t.length - 1; j <- 0 to t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = Math.exp(t(i)(j))
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def div(value: Double): Matrix2D ={ //this works?
        var t = matrix
        for(i <- 0 to t.length - 1; j <- 0 to t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = value / t(i)(j)
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def +(value: Double): Matrix2D = { //this works, I think
        var t = matrix
        for(i <- 0 to t.length - 1; j <- 0 to t(0).length - 1){
          t(i)(j) = t(i)(j) + value
        }
        Matrix2D(t)
      }

      def +(other: Matrix2D): Matrix2D = {//not sure if this works
        var l = Array.ofDim[Double](matrix.length, matrix(0).length)
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1) {
            l(i)(j) = matrix(i)(j) + other.matrix(i)(j)
          }
        }
        Matrix2D(l)
      }

      def shape(axis: Int) = matrix(axis).length //works

      def fix(axis: Int, value: Double): Unit ={ //works - sets a row/column to a value
        if (axis == 0){
          for(i <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            matrix(0)(i) = value
          }
        }

        if (axis == 1){
          for(j <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
            matrix(j)(0) = value
          }
        }
      }

      def sum: Double ={ //works, gets sum
        var s = 0.0
        for(i <- 0 to matrix.length - 1){
          for (j <- 0 to matrix(0).length - 1){
            s += matrix(i)(j)
          }
        }
        s
      }

      override def toString: String = { //obvious what this does
        var s = "["
        for(row <- matrix){
          s+="["
          for (cell <- row){
            s += cell
            s += " "
          }
          s += "]\n"
        }
        s+= "]"
        s
      }
    }

    object Matrix2D  { //obviously works
      def apply(X: Int, Y: Int): Matrix2D ={
        new Matrix2D(X,Y)
      }

      def apply(array: Array[Array[Double]]): Matrix2D ={
        var t = new Matrix2D(array(0).length, array(1).length)
        t.set(array)
        t
      }

      def rand(x: Int, y: Int): Matrix2D = {
        var t = new Matrix2D(x,y)
        t.populate
        t
      }
    }
```

Here is the Boltzmann Machine code:

```
    class rbm (val visible: Int, val hidden: Int){
      val seed = 1234
      var weights = Matrix2D(visible, hidden)
      var rgen = (x: Double, y: Double) => 0.1 * Math.sqrt(6 / (x + y))
      weights.populate(seed, rgen)
      weights.insert((1,1), 0)

      def train(data: Matrix2D, maxEpochs: Int = 1000, learningRate: Double = 0.1): Unit ={
        var numExamples = data.shape(0)
        data.insert(1, 1)

        for(epoch <- 1 to maxEpochs) {
          var posHiddenActivations = data dot weights
          var posHiddenProbs = logistic(posHiddenActivations)
          posHiddenProbs.fix(1, 1)
          var posHiddenStates = posHiddenProbs > Matrix2D.rand(numExamples, hidden + 1)
          var posAssociations = data.T dot posHiddenProbs
          //==============================================================================
          var negVisibleActivations = posHiddenStates dot weights.T
          var negVisibleProbs = logistic(negVisibleActivations)
          negVisibleProbs.fix(1,1)
          var negHiddenActivations = negVisibleProbs dot weights
          var negHiddenProbs = logistic(negHiddenActivations)
          var negAssociations = negVisibleProbs.T dot negHiddenProbs
          weights = weights + (((posAssociations - negAssociations) / numExamples) * learningRate)

          var error = ((data - negVisibleProbs)^2).sum
          println("Epoch " + epoch + ": error is " + error)
        }

      }

      def run_visible(data: Array[Array[Double]]): Unit ={

      }

      def run_hidden(data: Array[Array[Double]]): Unit ={

      }

      def daydream(numsamples: Int): Unit ={

      }

      private def logistic(matrix: Matrix2D): Matrix2D ={
        (matrix.exp(-matrix) + 1.0) div 1.0
      }

      /*
      def _logistic(self, x):
        return 1.0 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
       */
    }

    object rbm {
      def apply(visible: Int, hidden: Int): rbm ={
        new rbm(visible, hidden)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use libraries? (You'd use Numpy in Python, for example). If you can, take a look at the Breeze Matrix: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Data-Structures#densematrix

Comment: Your definition of `Matrix2D` class starts with a completely unrelated implicit conversion `bool2int`, immediately followed by another completely unrelated `MersenneTwister`. Nothing of it has anything to do with `Double`-matrices. Clean that up first, cover everything by tests. Only when you are sure that you can actually rely on your (or someone else's) matrix implementation, continue with the RBMs.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use libraries. The bool2int is for creating a true/false matrix when comparing Matrix2D to another Matrix2D, the randomGenerator is for populating a matrix with random values. I know that both the bool2int and randomGnerator works.